# Visual Basic for applications (excel) How to get sum of all checked checkboxes

Tags: vba, excel

I created a few checkboxes, which I select in a listbox, what can I do if I 
add a value to sum them up, I created it as a restaurant menu and I do not 
know how to sum them up, maybe somebody can help me.
I am a beginner in Visual Basic for Applications and I do not know how to make this . Maybe I need to add a new listbox where the values will be presented and then summed them up

```
`Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
ListBox1.AddItem CheckBox1.Caption
CheckBox1.Enabled = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox10_Change()
If CheckBox10.Value = True Then
ListBox1.AddItem CheckBox10.Caption
CheckBox10.Enabled = False
End If

 End Sub

 Private Sub CheckBox11_Change()
  If CheckBox11.Value = True Then
  ListBox1.AddItem CheckBox11.Caption
    CheckBox11.Enabled = False
     End If

      End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox12_Change()
     If CheckBox12.Value = True Then
       ListBox1.AddItem CheckBox12.Caption
       CheckBox12.Enabled = False
       End If

      End Sub

      Private Sub CheckBox2_Change()
     If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
    ListBox1.AddItem CheckBox2.Caption
    CheckBox2.Enabled = False
    End If

  End Sub

 Private Sub CheckBox3_Change()
 If CheckBox3.Value = True Then
 ListBox1.AddItem CheckBox3.Caption
 CheckBox3.Enabled = False
  End If

  End Sub

  Private Sub CheckBox4_Change()
 If CheckBox4.Value = True Then
 ListBox1.AddItem CheckBox4.Caption
 CheckBox4.Enabled = False
 End If

End Sub

 Private Sub CheckBox5_Change()
  If CheckBox5.Value = True Then
   ListBox1.AddItem CheckBox5.Caption
   CheckBox5.Enabled = False
 End If

 End Sub

  Private Sub CheckBox6_Change()
  If CheckBox6.Value = True Then
 ListBox1.AddItem CheckBox6.Caption
  CheckBox6.Enabled = False
 End If

  End Sub


 Private Sub CheckBox7_Change()
  If CheckBox7.Value = True Then
 ListBox1.AddItem CheckBox7.Caption
 CheckBox7.Enabled = False
  End If

 End Sub

 Private Sub CheckBox8_Change()
 If CheckBox8.Value = True Then
 ListBox1.AddItem CheckBox8.Caption
 CheckBox8.Enabled = False
  End If

  End Sub

 Private Sub CheckBox9_Change()
 If CheckBox9.Value = True Then
 ListBox1.AddItem CheckBox9.Caption
  CheckBox9.Enabled = False
   End If

  End Sub

  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  CheckBox1.Enabled = True
  CheckBox2.Enabled = True
   CheckBox3.Enabled = True
   CheckBox4.Enabled = True
   CheckBox5.Enabled = True
   CheckBox6.Enabled = True
   CheckBox7.Enabled = True
   CheckBox8.Enabled = True
    CheckBox9.Enabled = True
   CheckBox10.Enabled = True
    CheckBox11.Enabled = True
     CheckBox12.Enabled = True
      ListBox1.Clear

       End Sub

     Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
     MsgBox ("Ordered Successfully!")
      End Sub

      Private Sub Label1_Click()

       End Sub

      Private Sub Label2_Click()

     End Sub

     Private Sub Label3_Click()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label4_Click()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

    End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_Click()

    End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

I supposed the checkboxes caption has numeric values as caption ..
Try this code

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim ctl         As Control
Dim tot         As Double

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
        If ctl.Value = True And IsNumeric(ctl.Caption) Then
            tot = tot + Val(ctl.Caption)
        End If
    End If
Next ctl

MsgBox "Total = " & tot & Chr(10) & "Ordered Successfully"
End Sub
```

Comment: Won't work in the way that you think. `tot` should an integral type (`Short` or `Long`). In the example code, the `Caption` is more likely to be a descriptor of the item and not Numeric (use `tot = tot +1` instead). You should use `vbCRLF` or `vbLineFeed` instead of `Chr(10)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, it need to declare module level private variable `l_Chx As Byte` and increase/decrease it by 1 on every checkbox event to get qty of currently checked boxes.
.

Answer (score 0):

Because you add the items to a `ListBox`, you can simple use `ListBox1.ListCount` to return the number of items.

(Edit: The following is a general comment based on what a user would normally expect to do. However, the OP code includes disabling the checkbox when checked, so the user cannot uncheck an item.)

What is missing from your code is the case where someone unchecks an item (`CheckBoxX.Value = False` in your `CheckBoxX_Change` event handlers) - you must then remove the item from your `ListBox`. There will be plenty of examples on the internet for "VBA removing items from a ListBox".

Comment: user cannot uncheck checkboxes because they get disabled

Comment: @DisplayName: Good pick up, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to sum up labels captions

assuming that `Label1` caption has the price to be summed once `CheckBox1` is checked (the same for `Label2` and `CheckBox2`, etc...), then you may want to:

- add at the very top of your UserForm code pane

  ```
  Dim total As Double
  ```
- anywhere in your UserForm code pane:

  ```
  Private Sub CBChange(cb As MSForms.CheckBox)
      With cb
          If .Value Then
              Me.ListBox1.AddItem .Caption
              .Enabled = False
              total = total + Val(Me.Controls("label" & Replace(.Caption, "CheckBox", "")))
          End If
      End With
  End Sub
  ```
- change all your checkboxes `Change` event handler as follows:

  ```
  Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
       CBChange Me.ActiveControl
  End Sub

  Private Sub CheckBox2_Change()
       CBChange Me.ActiveControl
  End Sub

  ... and so on..
  ```

BTW you may want to change your `CommandButton1_Click` event handler as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim iCB As Long

    With Me
        For iCB = 1 To 12
            .Controls("CheckBox" & iCB).Enabled = True
        Next
        .ListBox1.Clear
    End With
End Sub
```